# Arquitetura para App Distribuida Descentralizada

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

## Ajuda

Pessoal. Preciso de uma grande ajuda para definir uma direção. Preciso desenvolver uma app multiplataforma(Android, WP e iOS) de forma distribuida e descentralizada. Seria uma aplicação multi-master, que significa não haver local central.

A referencia mais significativa que encontrei foi esta:
Architecture for a Decentralized Distributed Application
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131811/architecture-for-a-decentralized-distributed-application

Entendo que não deve haver maiores supresas no desenvolvimento do App propriamente dito, mas sim na sincronização das informações; nas replicações.

## Minha idéia é a seguinte no contexto das sincronizações e replicações:

- Definir a base de dados. Qual atenderia a demanda, sendo que usuários seriam na casa dos milhares?
- Sincronização por meio de arquivos xml's modulares, sendo desta forma a transmissão dos mesmos seria com base em timestamp dentro de um intervalo de período pré definido.
- Distribuição na rede por meio dos contatos? De que forma poderia ser disseminados estas atualizações na base de dados?

## Em relação a criptografia da base de dados:

- Sendo que a base estará em cada cliente, qual a melhor forma de proteger as informações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Base de Dados**

Base de dados no cliente (em especial mobile) não vejo como ser uma boa idéia. Primeiro pelo espaço consumido. Segundo pela falta de opções (acredito SQLite seja sua única ou praticamente única opção). Isto sem falar em consumo de recursos (banda, memória RAM, SSD e processador).

**Troca de Mensagens**

O overhead dos arquivos XML é relativamente alto. Se possível utilize algo menor, como Json, ou até um formato binário. Formatos binários além de tudo possuem a vantagem de normalmente serem mais rápidos para a serialização, deserialização. E compressão de dados é legal também, mas é necessário criar um threshold para se usar compressão (no caso de GZip ou ZLib, um número bom é perto dos 1200 bytes).

**Propagação da Informação**

Aqui é o mais complicado. O mais fácil seria utilizar um servidor que manteria quem está online e quem não está (equivalente ao Tracker do protocolo Torrent). Do contrário, estude DHT (acredito que ele funcione).

**Proteção das Informações**

Nisto você fica limitado à proteção oferecida pelo SGBD escolhido, a não ser que utilize uma tecnologia própria, ou criptografe todo o conteúdo do banco, mas isto reduziria o poder de execução de queries.

Não sei qual o objetivo do programa que quer desenvolver, mas não acho que esta começando certo. Dispositivos móveis não são poderosos, são caros, e são voláteis (no sentido de que se deterioram muito rápido). Isto sem contar a dificuldade de implementação.

Talvez Blockchain possa te ajudar. Mas sem saber o domínio da sua aplicação, não há como avaliar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. A aplicação seria com base em relacionamentos sociais, como uma rede social.

O que eu não consegui entender é como o Blockchain poderia ajudar.

Em relação a base de dados, acredito que a solução para criptografia esta neste post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption/7328825#7328825

Comment: @joaozarate O Blockchain é muito mais do que o processamento do Bitcoin. Ele é um conceito de descentralização completo. Tanto que estão implementando DNS e vários outros projetos em que sua única característica em comum é a total decentralização da informação. Claro, falei sem conhecer o domínio da sua aplicação, então pode ser que ele seja overkill ou simplesmente inapropriado ou absurdo. ;D